# Allow callbacks while blocking the main thread

Tags: c#, callback

Given the following Code:

```
public static void main()
{
    NotifyWindow.NotifyIcon.DoubleClick += new EventHandler(NotifyIconDoubleClick);
    NotifyWindow.Show(500, "some text", "some title");
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
}

private static void NotifyIconDoubleClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Clipboard.SetText("test");
}
```

(NotifyWindow being a wrapper of [NotifyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

I want to give the user the possibility to double click on the NotifyWindow so that the event is fired. Sadly this doesn't work with the Thread.Sleep() method since the callback gets freezed for this time.

Any way to archieve this?

Comment: I've update the title to reflect what the code "does". The general solution is to *don't* do it this way, but it is influenced by a bunch of factors - i.e. if NotifyWindow ran the callback in different thread (which it does not) then it "should world".

Comment: Thanks but how I can run the callback in another thread with having the main object not in the callback thread? Could you provide a example please?

Comment: What kind of app is this, a console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a message loop for the event handling to work. One way of achieving this is to create and "show" a hidden window, using `ShowDialog` or `Application.Run()`. If the action that should happen when you click the icon is showing a window, then it might be desirable to just create that window at the start already, but "show" it as hidden or minimized.

Comment: That is actually working but for some reason my application never exits after the main execution when I insert an Application.Run() after the NotifyWindow.Show(). Seems to be a blocking call. It has to exit after about 10 seconds.

Comment: You want the whole application to quit after 10 seconds (including the notification icon)? Then use a timer on the form that sends a close to it. `Application.Run()` will return when the corresponding window closes.